# Failed "Test Run" work item is actually a feature

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am running the OpsHubVisual Studio Online Migration Utility v1.2 and we got 11 failures that after we checked the work item ID found out it is actually a feature. Is there anything that I can do to get the utility to migrate these features and also is there a reason why the utility is recognizing them as tests rather than features?

Comment: Hi , Workitem and Test Entities such as Suite/Run/Result can have same ID so if the failures show that Test Run has failed then the ID shown in failures are that of Test Run and not feature . For further analysis can you send us logs from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online MIgration Utility\logs to ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: We bypassed these manually on our own TFS server and now we get no failures after just migrating Work Items. However, when the migration starts it fails then attempts a couple of more times and fails. I sent the logs from the above directory to the email address noted and attached some screen shots of the failed migration error.

Comment: So still doing work items but for some reason the migration progress keeps stopping regularly and I have to constantly restart it for it to pick up where it left off. Still no errors but really annoying that it keeps stopping.

Comment: Hi, it could be connectivity issue. Is there any such indications in the logs? (Or share the logs with us at the above mentioned address and we will analyze them)

Comment: I'm not losing any network connectivity and the computer is not going to sleep or anything else like that. I have emailed the new logs today. Thanks for any help you can give.